# Can we close the Iframe window from the page that is opened from the iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using iframe to open a user control in a project. This user control contains employee's information that save the employee information.

Now, when I display this user control from the iframe and save the employee information, on successfully save, I am showing an alert of "data successfully saved". Is it possible that when the data is successfully saved, it should automatically close the iframe? Below is the code

```
 $("#addAliasPopUp").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: width,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    show: { effect: 'blind' }
                }).find('iframe').attr("src", originalURL);
```

The value **originalURL** is the URL of the user control containing employee information. The URL is:

```
http://localhost/Demo/Modules/Employee/AddEmployee.aspx?SOURCE_HQ_REF=183229&HQ_SOURCE_NAME=DATAHUB&BUSINESS_RID=183296
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function in the parent document and call it from the iframe:

```
parent.destroyThisIframe();
```

Within the parent:

```
function destroyThisIframe(){
     $('iframe').remove();
}
```

Comment: how can i access this function when i am saving data from the user control called from the iframe?

Comment: I understand that you want to close the iframe from the iframe itself? That means in your iframe you would have something like this: <button type="button" onclick="parent.destroyThisIframe()">Close This Iframe</button>

Comment: I have this button inside the user control that the iframe displays. Can i access it inside the user control?

Comment: What's a user control? Is it within the iframe's DOM? If so then you can just call this code from there. If it's nested within something else, can we see the code or the rough structure of it?